# How to show zero when no result is returned in grouped joined query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compact down the number of 
queries on my (php) mysql database and 
I have the following problem:

For the last 10 posted comments, I show what the average comment 
rating is and whether there is an image associated with that comment

The MySQL is:

```
SELECT 
obj_images.fk_obj_id AS has_images,
AVG(obj_rating) AS rating
/*other joined tables with obj_comments omitted for clarity ...*/
FROM obj_comments
INNER JOIN obj_images
ON obj_comments.fk_obj_id=obj_images.fk_obj_id
GROUP BY obj_comments.fk_obj_id
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Even when there is no image associated with the comment, 
has_images still returns a value, ideally I would want to return zero when there are no images associated with the 
comment and 1 when there are images associated with it

What am I missing?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: I probably miss something but ... you use an `INNER JOIN` on `obj_comments.fk_obj_id=obj_images.fk_obj_id` so all result rows *will have* `obj_images.fk_obj_id` not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an outer join and `IFNULL()` instead of an inner join.

```
SELECT 
  AVG(c.obj_rating) AS avg_rating
  IFNULL(i.fk_obj_id, 0) AS has_images,
  /* ... */
FROM 
  obj_comments c
  LEFT JOIN obj_images i ON c.fk_obj_id = i.fk_obj_id
GROUP BY 
  c.fk_obj_id
ORDER BY 
  c.comment_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Also I think declaring table aliases is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand your question, but if you want to see if your request returns any result you can use `mysql_num_rows`

For example :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

`$num_rows = 0` if no result is returned.